# Struggling with file upload path on cURL

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

Beginner user on cURL. I'm really struggling with the path format used to upload a file through cURL.

```
curl -X POST https://XXXXXXXXX … -F file=@C:\Users\John\Downloads\test.csv
```

I keep getting the following error message "curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application"

Most of the examples provided start with file=@/home/, which is confusing as I don't have such directory to my understanding. Also, examples use "/" instead of "\". Why is it so?

Can anyone provide some feedback on how to properly write the path to a file?

Thanks!

Comment: Which curl are you using? The Windows10 port in \windows\system32? WSL and with what distro? cygwin? mingw? mingw64? gnuwin? something else? For the first, that syntax works for me. But this doesn't seem to be a programming question or problem.

Comment: Not sure I understand the questions. I downloaded the version for Windows 64 bit 7.72.0 from https://curl.haxx.se/download.html....

Comment: there is an alias in windows with the name "curl" for a program "Invoke-Webrequest" when we just run curl it actually runs that alias instead of the curl binary you downloaded .So try invoking curl using the absolute path of the curl binary you have downloaded and Paste the complete error you are getting

Comment: Maxim: there are 5 different builds of 7.72.0 for Windows-64 on that page, including one using cygwin -- did you use that? cygwin is more or less a port of Unix and uses different filename syntax than 'normal' Windows. For another (Viktor Szakats) the link indicates it uses mingw, which also changes some things but less. What happens if you try a different file? A nonexistent file(name)? @confusedgenius: the alias is only in powershell, not (the rest of) Windows -- and the error message format posted is definitely real curl NOT powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this! After some trials and errors, I figured out that the path's syntax should have used double backslash, so:

```
C:\\Users\\John\\Downloads\\test.csv
```

and not:

```
C:\Users\John\Downloads\test.csv
```

Honestly, I have never used this syntax before and don't understand why this is required. Your comments/input would certainly be appreciated.